# Taking snapshot of webcam in opencv without LED light

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, camera, webcam

I'm curious to how one could take a snap shot of a webcam without LED light being turned on in opencv python.

```
import cv2
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
check, frame = webcam.read()
cv2.imwrite('img.jpg', img=frame)
webcam.release()
```

Comment: Hi - it would help if you provided some code that you are working on, at the very least...

Comment: added code to the body